# FieldErro:Cannot resolve keyword 'date_added' into field. Choices are: data_added, id, text, topic, topic_id

Tags: python, django

#### I'm a Django beginner.There is a strange problem. I don't know why?

#### Here is the traceback.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/topics/1/

Django Version: 1.11.4
Python Version: 2.7.12
Template error:
In template /home/hu/learning_log/learning_logs/templates/learning_logs/base.html, error at line 0
   Cannot resolve keyword 'date_added' into field. Choices are: data_added, id, text, topic, topic_id   1 : <p>
   2 :   <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a>
   3 :   <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a>
   4 : </p>
   5 : 
   6 : {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

I hide the traceback

```
Exception Type: FieldError at /topics/1/
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'date_added' into field. Choices are: data_added, id, text, topic, topic_id
```

Comment: the place in view or template where you have written date_added change that to data_added

Comment: `'date_added' into field. Choices are: data_added...` You write data_added not date_added.

Comment: thank you. It's the solution.  A stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the django version you are using, but the solution should be in the URLs.py. Use  `id`  instead of `date_added`.
Something like this:

```
path('' ", ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.object.all().order_by(" id")[:10], template_name="blog/home.html),
```

So instead of `order_by("date_added")` use `order_by("id")`